# Get sum of tuples having same first and second value

Tags: python, tuples

I want to sum the last value of each tuple within the list whose first and second values are identical.

```
data = [('Microsoft', 'A001', 4.5, 20), ('Dell', 'A002', 8.9, 10), ('Acer', 'A001', 7.5, 5), ('Dell', 'A001', 2.5, 8), ('Microsoft', 'C002', 3.5, 10), ('Microsoft', 'A001', 4.5, 15)]
```

- first value: manufacturer
- second value: article number
- third value: price
- fourth value: quantity

How can I find all the matches **based on the first and second values** (Microsoft + A001), and output the quantity as a sum?

Expected result:

```
result = [('Microsoft', 'A001', 4.5, 35), ('Dell', 'A002', 8.9, 10), ('Acer', 'A001', 7.5, 5), ('Dell', 'A001', 2.5, 8), ('Microsoft', 'C002', 3.5, 10)]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You forgot to include your attempt at solving this problem.

Comment: Take a look at `itertools.groupby`.

Comment: What if you had `('A','B',0,0)` and `('A','B',1,0)`; what should show up in the result (particularly for the price)?

Comment: @ScottHunter That is a very good hint. Thank you. In this case, the higher price should be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now received the following solution to my problem through other means, which I wanted to share with you:

```
result = []
while data:
    for i in data[:]:
        compare = list(filter(lambda l: l[0] == i[0] and l[1] == i[1], data))
        total = 0
        for s in compare:
            total += s[-1]
            data.remove(s)
        result.append((i[0], i[1], i[2], i[3], total))
        break
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
dic = {}
for item in data:
    dic[item[:-1]] = dic.get(item[:-1],0) + item[-1]
data = [item+(dic[item],) for item in dic.keys()]
print(data)
>> [('Microsoft', 'A001', 4.5, 35), ('Dell', 'A002', 8.9, 10), ('Acer', 'A001', 7.5, 5), ('Dell', 'A001', 2.5, 8), ('Microsoft', 'C002', 3.5, 10)]
```

If the price is the same per article number and manufacterer, but only the quantity differed, you could do it like this. This code makes a dictionary with as key, the first 3 elements of an item from your data, and the value as quantity. Iterate over the data and add all quantities accordingly, then, get the data back into the original format by joining the keys and values as such.

Comment: It should be `dic[item[:2]] = dic.get(item[:2],0) + item[-1]` since the OP states *I want to sum the last value of each tuple within the list whose first and second values are identical.*

Comment: @dawg In principle, this solution works, but I have not considered the problem with the different price. I also have another list, which also contains the item name, which is also not always identical. This results in two values in the list, which are different, but are needed in the result in one of the versions.

Comment: @dawg How can I define the highest price and the "longest" name as a new value from the list?

`[('Microsoft', 'A001', 'Article Name', 4.5, 20), ('Dell', 'A002', 8.9, 10), ('Microsoft', 'A001', 'Article - Name', 2.5, 15)]`

Result:

`[('Microsoft', 'A001', 'Article - Name', 4.5, 35), ('Dell', 'A002', 8.9, 10)]`

Comment: You need to define rules on how `'Article - Name'` is considered a match for `'Article Name'` and what is also considered a match and what isn't. For that example, you could split into words and compare the lists. Clearly your problem needs further definition...

Answer (score 1):

```
def add_tup(data):
    d = {}
    for tup in data:
        key = tup[:-1]
        if key not in d:
            d[key] = 0
        d[key] += tup[3]
    
    lst = [key + (d[key],) for key in d.keys()]
    return lst
```

Assuming that if *manufacturer* and *article* are equal then the *price* will be equal as well. Step(1) make a dictionary with the key being the tuple with the *quantity* sliced out. If the keys are equal add their *quantities*... this will be the value of the dictionary. Step(2) create lst adding the key tuple and the new *quantity* sum. If you are not familiar with list comprehensions here is an alternative to creating the list.

```
lst = []
for key in d.keys():
    tup = key + (d[key],)
    lst.append(tup)
return lst
```